# Javascript - Simple Jquery Set CSS Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Why won't this set the css for the .btn-post element.  I've tried putting it in a function as well.

```
var variable = "hsla(359, 61%, 30%, 1);"

$('.btn-post').css('background', variable );
```

Comment: you could use a semicolon after your first line

Comment: I've tried it.  Still no luck.

Comment: take the ; outside of quotes

Comment: It does work: http://jsfiddle.net/32bfW/

Comment: And which browser are you using to test? IE8 won't support HSLa colors.

Comment: Then it is a loading order issue.  Thank you bfavaretto.  I have this in a complex backbone application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you need a `doc ready` handler for it:

```
$(function(){
   var variable = "hsla(359, 61%, 30%, 1)";
   $('.btn-post').css('background', variable );
});
```

Comment: Sorry, this was the problem.  Loading issue.  You're right.  Tahnks Jai

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   var variable = "hsla(359, 61%, 30%, 1)";
   $('.btn-post').css('background-color', variable );
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/)